# Algorithm to fill a 2D array in a preset manner

Tags: java

Hello I'm trying to figure out an algorithm to fill a 2D array to the way that this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/29MPM.jpg   10X10 is set up. With the grass, wall, notepad and endpoint objects locations in the 10X10 are set in the individual arrays, through this they are looped through and set into the 2D array. This is horrendous hard coding I need to be able to correct. I'm struggling in thinking of an algorithm which could perform this without extravagant lines. I would like to ask specifically what I should do to solve this issue. Could you offer me advice on solving this problem?

```
   Grass   Grass   Grass    Wall    null    null    Wall   Grass   Grass   Grass
   Grass   Grass   Grass    Wall    null    null    Wall   Grass   Grass   Grass
   Grass   Grass   Grass    Wall    null    null    Wall   Grass   Grass   Grass
   Grass   Grass    Wall    null    Note    Note    null    Wall   Grass   Grass
   Grass   Grass    Wall    Note    Wall    Wall    Note    Wall   Grass   Grass
   Grass    Wall    null    null    Wall    Wall    null    null    Wall   Grass
    Wall    null    null    null    Wall    Wall    null    null    null    Wall
   Grass    Wall    null    Note    Wall    Wall    Note    null    Wall   Grass
   Grass    Wall    Wall    null    Note    Note    null    Wall    Wall   Grass
   Grass   Grass    Wall    Wall     End     End    Wall    Wall   Grass   Grass
```

This is the current program.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class GameField {

    private String[][] field;
    private String grass, wall, note, end;
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrayG;
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrayW;
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrayN;
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrayE;

    public GameField() {
        field = new String[10][10];
        grass = "Grass";
        wall = "Wall";
        note = "Note";
        end = "End";
        arrayG = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 38, 39, 40, 41, 48, 49, 50, 59, 70, 79, 80, 89, 90, 91, 98, 99));
        arrayW = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(3, 6, 13, 16, 23, 26, 32, 37, 42, 44, 45, 47, 51, 54, 55, 58, 60, 64, 65, 69, 71, 74, 75, 78, 81, 82, 87, 88, 92, 93, 96, 97));
        arrayN = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(34, 35, 43, 46, 73, 76, 84, 85));
        arrayE = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(94, 95));
        fillField();
    }

    public void checkField(int x, int y) {

    }

    private void fillField() {
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                if (arrayG.contains(k)) {
                    field[i][j] = grass;
                }
                else if (arrayW.contains(k)){
                    field[i][j] = wall;
                }
                else if (arrayN.contains(k)){
                    field[i][j] = note;
                }
                else if (arrayE.contains(k)){
                    field[i][j] = end;
                }
                k++;
            }
        }
        print();

    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%8s", field[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does your data come from?

Comment: The data as in positions of the objects, grass, walls, endpoints, notepads are preset like seen in the imgur picture. The data as in the numbers which are written in the arraylists are the block numbers that equal their position. i.e. 0 equals the first block, the 0 - 0 position in a 2D array.

Comment: Do you have your "picture" in text form?  Then you can read the file and fill your matrix.

Comment: I thought that the text output of the code which is the wanted result, served as that. The first code indentation is the text output. The text form of the picture. The nulls represent empty space. Could you assist me in figuring out how this would be possible? I'm interested. I also would like to ask if this is a good practice in programming terms? Is this way considered "hard coding" which degrades program quality?

Comment: Open Excel spreadsheet and fill it with your "words".  Save it as CSV (comm-separated file).  Read this file into your array with `Scanner` or any  other i/o class.

Comment: That is good to know. Thank you. What do you think of my questions?

Comment: Have a look:  https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs160/.Spring15/assignments/P6/files/Maze.java